# Not able to sort Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Tried to sort the numbers given manually.
Numbers given are :[1,10,8,9,4,6,5,2,7]
To sort by finding the smallest element first in the whole list,then removing from the original list ( list_0 ) and adding/appending to new list ( list_final ).Need [1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] as output,where Did i go wrong ?

```
list_0=[1,10,8,9,4,6,5,2,7]
list_final=[]
small=100
for i in list_0:
    for j in range(len(list_0)):
        if i<small:
            small=i
            list_0.remove(small)
            list_final.insert(j,small)
print("original list :",list_0)
print("sorted list",list_final)
```

OUTPUT coming :

original list : [10, 8, 9, 4, 6, 5, 2, 7]

sorted list [1]

Comment: never change the list you are iterating over! (`list_0` in this case). this will almost always end in tears. and why not just use python's sort?

Comment: You would never do it this way in Python. Is there a reason why you don't use `sorted(list_0)`? Also, "compiler-error"??

Comment: @hiroprotagonist thank you for your suggestion. sorted() is great but trying to do the internal process all by my self.

Comment: @hop  compile-error was wrong tag mate.sry for that !

Comment: sorting is an art! there are *many* algorithms for it out there. which one are you trying to implement?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist  selection sort mate !  
selecting the minimum element from the list ,then pushing to new list .iterating till the whole list gets sorted.

Comment: after the first for-loop iteration `small` gets set to `1` which causes the `if` check to fail for all subsequent elements in `list_0`, so `list_final` only gets the first element in `list_0`. The selection sort algorithm is in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort, a python implementation is in http://www.geekviewpoint.com/python/sorting/selectionsort

Comment: added one more version of the code. shorter & (for my taste) more pythonic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a more pythonic version of selection sort. this is just the python translation of the [selection sort code from wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort#Implementation). the code is well commented there...

```
lst = [1, 10, 8, 9, 4, 6, 5, 2, 7]

for i in range(len(lst)):
    min_index = lst.index(min(lst[i:]))   # find the next min_index > i
    if min_index != i:
        lst[i], lst[min_index] = lst[min_index], lst[i]  # swap

print(lst)  # [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

The final code after all your helps guys.Thank you !

@hop  @andrepogg @Godson Rapture Chijioke @hiro protagonist

```
list_0=[1,10,8,9,4,6,5,2,7]
list_final=[]
small=0
for i in range(len(list_0)):
    small=min(list_0)
    list_final.append(small)
    list_0.remove(small)
print (list_final)
```

OUTPUT:

[1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do something like this:

```
list_0 = [1,10,8,9,4,6,5,2,7]
list_final = sorted(list_0)
```

Comment: output came very precisely but i am trying to do without any predefined functions help.

Comment: what type of sorting does this "sorted()  function" perform internally ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I used my phone and came up with this code. 
I am kinda busy,but I hope this helps you. I am also coming up with a [python list tutorial very soon.](http://coolpythoncodes.com)

I will include your problem and give a better solution.

Right now am busy.

Here's the code.

```
    list_O=[1,10,8,9,4,6,5,2,7]
    list_final=[]
    index=0
    #min_item=min(list_O)
    while index<len(list_O):
        min_item=min(list_O)
        list_final.append(min_item)
        list_O.remove(min_item)
        index+=1
    print (list_final)
```

Here's an image :

[The screenshot of the solution.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWZNA.png)

Comment: list_O=[1,10,8,9,4,6,5,2,7]
    list_final=[]
    index=0
    #min_item=min(list_O)
    while index<len(list_O):
        min_item=min(list_O)
        list_final.append(min_item)
        list_O.remove(min_item)
        index+=1
    print (list_final)

Answer (score 0):

Okay... Am still on your problem...

Try this code out.

You will get the desired result

```
    list_O=[1,10,8,9,4,6,5,2,7]
    list_final=[]
    for i in list_O:
        for j in range(len(list_O)):
            min_item=min(list_O)
            list_final.append(min_item)
            list_O.remove(min_item)
    print (list_final)
```